# How can I open my React Native App from the browser?

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, applinks

I would like to open my app from the browser.

example: I open a browser, type in: `https://open.my.app`, or `app://www.example.com` and have my app as an option come up.

I read about Deep Links and I am quite sure I set up my project properly, YET nothing happens when I either try to type and run: `https://open.my.app, app://www.example.com`

My AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.somemobileapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Change these two in the future to a proper one -->
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" />
            <data android:scheme="app" android:host="open.my.app" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So even after this, it's not working.

Comment: This will help you : https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e

Comment: Yeah, I followed it but no success, I will update the post.

Answer (score 0):

I know it will sound strange but keeping the data tag on first worked for me

```
<intent-filter>
<!-- data on first -->
     <data android:scheme="http" android:host="abc.in"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, I think you need to publish your app to playstore to  make the switch turn on automatically after verification for default link opening, if you are debugging you need to enable it manually by going to Appinfo

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true"> <!-- for default support to open, only works after publish -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <!-- supported web addresses -->
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.google.com" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*.google.com" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="google.com" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="google.com" />
        <data android:scheme="google"/>
        
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**Reference Images:**

- https://imgur.com/7gEphcg
- https://imgur.com/B76b3mu
- https://imgur.com/9ZgA48Y